# Permission denied from Bastion to Private ec2

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh, bastion-host, jumphost

I have set up a bastion public ec2 host and also setup a private ec2 which security inbound rule is set to ssh from only bastion security group. But, there is two different scenario. I have added both private key to ssh-agent and i'm trying this from windows machine with cmd.exe

1. When I try to access with this command below it can access without any probem-
   `ssh -J ubuntu@ip-public ubuntu@ip-private`
2. When I access the bastion server first I can login successfully, but from bastion I try with this command but is failing-
   `ssh ubuntu@ip-private`

`channel 1: chan_shutdown_read: shutdown() failed for fd 7 [i0 o0]: Not a socket ubuntu@privateip: Permission denied (publickey).`

I have tried multiple times but returning same error. Don't know how professionaly this bastion should setup. Looking for help and suggestions on this. Never tried before.

Comment: **Side-note:** An alternative way to access the private instance is by using [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html). It uses an agent on the instance to establish the connection, so does not require a Bastion.

Answer (score 0):

Note.  I got this exercise working from an Ubuntu WSL terminal window.

The upshot is that you need an SSH server in order to receive ssh requests from clients.

1. Make sure your Windows instance is running
2. RDP into the instance (one-time only)
3. Type *powershell* in command line to toggle out of cmd
4. Run the following command to determine if you have OpenSSH.Server installed

> Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

5. Install the service

> Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0

6. After a minute or two it installs (be patient)
7. Set service to start service automatically in case you stop instance

> Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'

8. Run the OpenSSH.Server service, called sshd

> Start-Service sshd

9. Exit the instance shell and RDP session
10. Go back to your shell on your computer
11. Run your customary ssh command to get into the EC2 instance.  You'll be prompted for a password. There are ways to get around that.